# Objective C finder tags searching

Tags: objective-c, macos, tags, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

Since Mavericks, OS X introduced tags in the Finder.

[image: Tagging a file]

[image: Searching for tags]

I'd like to know if there is any easy way to search for all files with a given tag.
For example, get all the files (possibly within a certain directory) that are tagged with "Favorite".
I know I can get the tags off an individual file using NSURL. Using that I *could* just query the entire file system myself by iterating over directories and files.
But I'm wondering if the Objective C API has a faster way to do it.

Comment: As a starting point see how to do Spotlight searches from code: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001843-BBCFBCAG - i am using that to search for filenames have never looked into tags though. Probably through kMDItemFSLabel ...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Volker. That got me on the right path.
(But only *after* I spent three hours writing a framework that would iterate over each and every file checking to see if it matched the tag, which is an extravagantly inefficient way to do it.)

So, here's a class that will search and return all files marked with a given tag.

FindTaggedFiles.h

```
@interface FindTaggedFiles : NSObject
{
    @private NSString* _tag;
    @private NSMetadataQuery* query;
}

-(id)initWithTag:(NSString*)tag withHandler:(void(^)(NSArray*))handler;
-(void)startSearch;
@end
```

FindTaggedFiles.m

```
@interface FindTaggedFiles()
@property (copy) void (^completionHandler)(NSArray*);
@end

@implementation FindTaggedFiles

-(id)initWithTag:(NSString *)tag withHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))handler
{
    self = [super init];
    _completionHandler = handler;
    self->_tag = tag;
    return self;
}

-(void)startSearch
{
    query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc]init];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryDidUpdate:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:query];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(initalGatherComplete:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:query];

    NSPredicate *searchPredicate;
    NSString* predicate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"kMDItemUserTags == '%@'", self->_tag ];
    searchPredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicate];
    [query setPredicate:searchPredicate];

    NSArray *searchScopes;
    searchScopes=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSMetadataQueryUserHomeScope,nil];
    [query setSearchScopes:searchScopes];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortKeys=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:(id)kMDItemDisplayName ascending:YES];
    [query setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortKeys]];

    [query startQuery];
}

- (void)queryDidUpdate:sender;
{
    NSLog(@"A data batch has been received");
}

- (void)initalGatherComplete:sender;
{
    [query stopQuery];

    NSMutableArray* files = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSUInteger i=0;
    for (i=0; i < [query resultCount]; i++) {
        NSMetadataItem *theResult = [query resultAtIndex:i];
        [files addObject:theResult];
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:query];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:query];
    self->query=nil;

    _completionHandler(files);
}
```

Then you would use it like this

```
FindTaggedFiles* finder = [[FindTaggedFiles alloc]initWithTag:@"Disneyland" withHandler:^(NSArray* files){
    //do something with the files
}];

[finder startSearch];
```

The NSMetaDataQuery works asynchronously, so I designed this class to require an async block as handler code in the init method. But, in the documentation, I believe it mentions that you don't have to run the search async.

My class is an adaptation of [the code in the Apple documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryingMetadata.html)

Also note: this doesn't search within a specific directory as such. The meta data query runs in a specific *scope*. A scope can be the user's home directory (like in this example), the user's iCloud, all attached drives, and a couple others. The specifics are covered in the documentation I linked to just above under "Limiting the search scope".

I believe you could further customize the query to limit it to a directory.

Comment: Your code has an issue: It stops the query after receiving the initial callback. That's not good as I've seen it happen, especially when searching on network volumes, that the initial callback returns nothing, but only the `queryDidUpdate:` callback will return the results.